# Initializing pointer constant to a field inside another pointer constant?

Tags: c, pointers, low-level

I have the following code I'm using within a header file:

```
static const struct ExecDataABI* const qtumExec = (const struct ExecDataABI* const) EXEC_DATA_ADDRESS;
static const UniversalAddressABI* const qtumSender = (const UniversalAddressABI* const) &qtumExec->sender;
```

Basically there is a read-only section of memory that has the ExecDataABI info in it. Fetching qtumExec->sender is a very common operation, so I want to break it out into a direct convenience variable so that there is less typing required etc.

With this code the compiler complains "initializer element is not constant". Is there anyway to express this properly to the compiler? I can of course count bytes in the struct, but that is cumbersome and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as a preprocessor macro, and the compiler should optimize it.